# Need to add wildcard to change URL location of documents in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, wildcard

This is my first time here and posting. If I haven't done something quite right in formatting my question or communication, please let me know and so I can correct it in the future.

I have been pretty good at working inside the database until now. I need to do a search replace on this:

> UPDATE wp_posts SET 'post_content'
>      = REPLACE ('post_content',
>      'http://somedomain.com/12345/678/910/.doc',
>      'http://newdomain.com/newfolder/.doc');

Change the URLs in the content area of the WP post so that they stop pointing to the old location but to the new folder which is where I uploaded the new docs.  I think I need a wildcard or something in there were the numbers are because the numbers of the file folders will be different. The docs aren't in the same file folders. I tried using and asterisk (*) in place of the numbers but it didn't work. Can someone help me with the proper string I need to use? The outcome should just be that all URLs for the docs be changed to the new folder location. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?

Just add back slash '\' before asterisk (*) .

Try below code:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET 'post_content' = REPLACE ('post_content', 'http://somedomain.com/12345/678/910/\*.doc', 'http://newdomain.com/newfolder/\*.doc');
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. mySql is the database. Using with WordPress. I will give this a try right now.